# how to apply style to input text when certain key is pressed through jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div in which user inputs email id's seperated by comma, I wanted to color them in as `background-color:green` when a valid email is entered and user enter comma for next email address, I'm stuck at applying it though my function is called on press of comma but I'm not able to apply style in css through jquery
here is my code

```js
$('.team-btn').click(function() {
  $('.team-intro').replaceWith($(".team-invite").clone().show());

  $('#invite-emails').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 188) {
      $val = $(this).val();
      $(this).val.apply("<span style='background-color:green'>");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="team-intro">
  <p>XXXX is a Free to use, Invite your team and get started today</p>
  <button class="team-btn">Invite Now</button>
</div>

<div class="team-invite" style="display:none;">
  <p>Enter emails and we will invite your mates to join you.</p>
  <input type="text" id='invite-emails' name='email' placeholder='enter emails here' size="30">
  <br>
  <!--<div data-value=""  id='style-email' style="padding-left: 12px; padding-right: 12px;">-->
  <p id='subtext'>You can enter multiple emails with comma</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't 'apply' anything to the `val()` function. You also can't add HTML inside the value of the `input` and have it interpreted by the renderer.

To set the styling of an element you're best to add/remove a pre-defined CSS class. Try this:

```js
$('.team-btn').click(function() {
  $('.team-intro').replaceWith($(".team-invite").clone().show());

  $('#invite-emails').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 188) {
      $(this).addClass('foo');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.foo { background-color: #0C0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="team-intro">
  <p>XXXX is a Free to use, Invite your team and get started today</p>
  <button class="team-btn">Invite Now</button>
</div>

<div class="team-invite" style="display:none;">
  <p>Enter emails and we will invite your mates to join you.</p>
  <input type="text" id='invite-emails' name='email' placeholder='enter emails here' size="30">
  <br>
  <!--<div data-value=""  id='style-email' style="padding-left: 12px; padding-right: 12px;">-->
  <p id='subtext'>You can enter multiple emails with comma</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to apply CSS only to text till `comma` the second email address should again has to get background color as green, & not like what it is right now as it is applying background color to textbox itself

Comment: That's not possible in a form control - although you can change the text colour, if that's what you mean. Change the CSS to `color: #0C0;`

Comment: Any idea how we can approach and achieve my requirement

Comment: Well, this does meet your requirement - it sets the background of the control to green when you enter a comma...

Comment: yes, I might not correctly written it , but I need to set background-color:green to only Email address text entered by user and for each such email address after comma is pressed

Comment: In that case you'd need to print the email addresses in separate elements and wrap them in there. Something like a tag well. Better yet, put the email addresses in their own inputs. Either way, that is way out of the scope of this question. I'd suggest you start a new question about splitting out the content of a single element instead

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use `$(this).css({'background-color' : 'green'});` instead of `$(this).val.apply("<span style='background-color:green'>");`

```js
$('.team-btn').click(function(){
            $('.team-intro').replaceWith($(".team-invite").clone().show());
            
            $('#invite-emails').keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 188) {
        $val = $(this).val();
        $(this).css({'background-color' : 'green'});
    } else {
      $(this).css({'background-color' : ''});
    }
});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="team-intro">
            <p>XXXX is a Free to use, Invite your team and get started today</p>
            <button class="team-btn">Invite Now</button>
        </div>

        <div class="team-invite" style="display:none;">
            <p>Enter emails and we will invite your mates to join you.</p>
            <input type="text" id='invite-emails' name='email'  placeholder='enter emails here' size="30">
            <br>
            <!--<div data-value=""  id='style-email' style="padding-left: 12px; padding-right: 12px;">-->
            <p id='subtext'>You can enter multiple emails with comma</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: I need to apply background color only till , after that once user enter new email it should again turns in new green color as a `tag`

Comment: Well, thats not possible in a form-control. You can do that with other HTML tags but not possible in form-elements. And this code does meet, what you wanted to achieve. It turns into green, whenever a comma is entered.

Answer (score 0):

To apply css-style in JQuery you can use `.css()` method